# Can we call a function inside Head Tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was just wondering if we could call a function inside `<Head>` tags to set title dynamically, calling an API in componentDidMount and then displaying the content if isLoaded in the state is set to true. The data has 3 sport types i.e Football, Cricket, Golf and I have to set Title based on these conditions.

```
    render() {
        if(isLoaded){
        return(
        const { dataFromApI } = this.state;              
                  <Head>
                    <title>{this.TitleHelper(dataFromApI)}</title>
                  </Head>
```

Currently, I have implemented this and it seems to set my title perfectly. I wanted to know if this is a good way to set the Title or are there any other ways to call a function and then set the Title Tags.

```
TitleHelper = (data) =>{
if(data.sport === 'Football')
{return `${data.StarName} | is a FootBaller`}
else if(... === 'cricket'){
return `CRICKET | ${data.StarName}}
else{return 'GOLF'}
}
```

is this a good approach to solve my problem?

Comment: the way you set your title is good but I would suggest using a `switch condition`, in case you meant that you want to set the document title use `document.title` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I have to wait for the data from the API which is called in componentDidMount, also coming to the switch statement you recon I use it before the return statement instead of calling a function?

Comment: since you're waiting for the data from the api, add a property `isLoading` and then you can check if the data is retrieved successfully eg. (data is not null)  view the result. if you want the best practice, you have to take care of the request cases (success or an error that might be internal or no connection depending on the status of the response)

Comment: check this https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: yes, im taking care of the request cases. only if the request-response code is successful im setting the state isloaded as true. My concern is that is this a good way to set title for the page?